# Users that haven't logged in during last n months

Tags: mysql

I would like to remove users that haven't logged in for given period, but period will be choosen by me later based on results.

So i need report in which I will receive number of users which haven't logged in, during last 1 month, 2 months ... n months.

I don't quite know how to achive moving period in single mysql query.

Extracting these users for given period is easy:

```
SELECT count(distinct id) from tmp_last_login 
WHERE last_login <= DATE_SUB(now(), interval 1 month)
```

But how to achive such report for n months?

Expected result:

```
**interval**    **cnt**
1                 xxx
2                 xxx
3                 xxx
4                 xxx
5                 xxx
...               xxx
n                 xxx
```

Comment: Please show your expected result in a tabular form

Comment: what's the data type of `last_login `? `timestamp or date`?

Answer (score 4):

The following query will return count of `distinct ids` for `each month difference` within the interval of `10 months from now`.

```
SELECT
12 * (YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(last_login)) + (MONTH(CURDATE()) - MONTH(last_login)) AS months,
count(DISTINCT id) cnt
FROM
    tmp_last_login
WHERE   last_login >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),   INTERVAL 10 MONTH)
GROUP BY months;
```

**OR**

You can use `PERIOD_DIFF` function as well.

```
SELECT
PERIOD_DIFF(DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%Y%m'),DATE_FORMAT(last_login,'%Y%m')) AS months,
count(DISTINCT id) cnt
FROM
    tmp_last_login
WHERE   last_login >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),   INTERVAL 10 MONTH)
GROUP BY months;
```

---

**Note:**

### If you have multiple `last_login` entries for the same user then you need to find the `maximum last login` time for each user and then do the rest.

```
SELECT
PERIOD_DIFF(DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%Y%m'),DATE_FORMAT(t.max_last_login,'%Y%m')) AS months,
count(t.id) cnt
FROM
    (
            SELECT 
                id,
                MAX(last_login) max_last_login
            FROM tmp_last_login
            GROUP BY id
        ) AS t
WHERE   t.max_last_login >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),   INTERVAL 10 MONTH)
GROUP BY months;
```

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e2538/4/0)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    ((last_login - UNIX_TIMESTAMP()) / 2629743) monthsSinceLastLogin
FROM tmp_last_login
WHERE last_login - UNIX_TIMESTAMP() > 2629743
GROUP BY id
HAVING max(last_login) = last_login
```

Assumption: You are using a unix timestamp that is counted in seconds.
2629743 is approx. one month in seconds.

With the GROUP BY and HAVING part you make sure you pick only the latest login. 
With the WHERE part you make sure you pink only records that are at least one month old.

Comment: @xter Did I understand you correctly that you want a list of users that haven't been logged in since a certain period? 
OR: Do you want to know how many users logged in durring a certain period?